# Need help content type showing?

Tags: drupal

I am bit of a drupal newbie. I'm trying to find out how I can display my content types on my page?

For example I have a bunch of content type called clients with a name and logo and a page called clients. I want to display the clients content type on that page.

Any help?

Comment: You should use the Views module for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to achieve this.  Using Views, you can create pages, blocks, panels, etc.  From the Views project page:

> What is Views
>
> The Views module provides a flexible method for Drupal site designers
>   to control how lists and tables of content (nodes in Views 1, almost
>   anything in Views 2) are presented. Traditionally, Drupal has
>   hard-coded most of this, particularly in how taxonomy and tracker
>   lists are formatted.
>
> This tool is essentially a smart query builder that, given enough
>   information, can build the proper query, execute it, and display the
>   results. It has four modes, plus a special mode, and provides an
>   impressive amount of functionality from these modes.
>
> Among other things, Views can be used to generate reports, create
>   summaries, and display collections of images and other content.

For more information on Views, take a look at the [Documentation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/views).

For your use-case:

Create a new view (of type "node"), create a new display (page), add the fields from the content type that you want to display, choose a type of display (table, grid, HTML list, etc), add a filter on `Node: type` to only show nodes of type: client.

That is a basic start, you can also choose how many client nodes to display, if you want paging, different sort orders and much more.